# Getting location with new Google Api Client with Google Play Services

Tags: android, location, google-play-services, google-api-client, google-plus-signin

I moved to the new Client Api model of Google Play services when it came out a year ago. I was just using the Location API so there wasn't any problem then. Now, I'm implementing Google+ login in my app and so my mGoogleApiClient object is handling Plus API and Location API.

The problem with this is that when the user is not logged in, onConnectionFailed gets called and as a result the location is not available.

I'd like to ask for some suggestions of how you have implemented this and what are the best practices? I checked the dev bytes videos, the documentation but couldn't find a scenario where one of the services they used were Location. Regardless of the fact that the user logs in or not, there are some features of the app that are available and location is key to that so I'd like that call to be successful every time.

Please let me know if you have some experience with GoogleApiClients.

Here's my GoogleApiClient build call :

```
mGoogleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this)
                            .addApi(LocationServices.API)
                            .addApi(Plus.API)
                            .addScope(Plus.SCOPE_PLUS_LOGIN)
                            .addConnectionCallbacks(this)
                            .addOnConnectionFailedListener(this)
                            .build();
```

Thanks,

Comment: Same problem here.... Did you solve this problem ?

Comment: No, I had to use different client for location and a different one for Google Plus. I couldn't think of any other way to move forward. However, I don't think this was the way it was designed to be used. It's basically the same as having different clients for different services.